# Speed issue with omnisharp go-to-definition

Tags: performance

Getting a rather sizable speed issue with using go-to-definition from omnisharp. Ran the profiler, and received nearly 50% of the cpu time dedicated between:

isearch-printing-char

and

omnisharp-go-to-definition

The former was 9% larger than the latter. Anyone else experience this issue?

Modes I'm currently running on the buffers that are starting the function call:

C#, company, flychec, yas, projectile, ws

Comment: If someone would be so kind as to tag this for me with omnisharp, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the question here? Is it "how do I speed up omnisharp?"

Comment: Show us the (relevant part of the) actual profiler output.

Comment: @zck the question was the performance issue with omnisharp's go-to-definition function. I posted in the question the profiler output that was relevant.

isearch-printing-char consumed 650 cpu samples
omnisharp-go-to-definition consumed 450 cpu samples.

Although as I answered the question below, killing the isearch resolved the overall performance issue I was experiencing

Answer (score 0):

On the second go around with go-to-definition, isearch-printing-char was removed. I may have either killed that command, or it was no longer needed. Uncertain, but with isearch-printing-char removed, the speed was returned to "fairly" normal for go-to-definition opening in the current buffer.

Current samples for omnisharp go-to-definition: 98 (down from around 500), and overall samples down from 1600 to 374.